# Skip common/duplicate parts while indexing web pages with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I don't have any experience with ElasticSearch yet, but from what I read I think it suits most my needs.  I have a web scraper  which scrapes pages of certain domains. 
I want to feed these pages into SE and offer a front end interface to search the scraped content. I'm building some sort of vertical search engine.

But as we all know, web pages of one host often only contain a little bit of unique content, a great part of the pages are common. Footer, header, menu etc. are the same on every page.

Does ElasticSearch have some build in intelligence that can filter out the common parts and only search the real content??

Answer (score 0):

It's not terribly difficult to pump web content into Elastic, so I'll assume you have that down. =)

I think this article is fantastic for understanding how to index/search web pages:

http://blog.urx.com/urx-blog/2014/9/4/the-science-of-crawl-part-1-deduplication-of-web-content

It's a complex problem and they have some great detail. There is nothing I know of natively in Elastic that has intelligence to help you eliminate duplicates etc.

Answer (score 0):

The strategy you need to adopt here would be to create a unique key per document. Taking checksum using sha1 or similar algorithm will do the job for getting the unique key. Make this the document ID so that only one page occurs at all point of time. Again use _create API to index if you dont want new duplicates to be indexed ( More efficient ) , and in case you want the new ones to be the document use normal indexing.

In case you need to modify the orginal document in case of disocvery of duplicate document , use upser.

I have explained a great deal of this in this [blog](https://qbox.io/blog/minimizing-document-duplication-in-elasticsearch).